# Tables. Update cell if another cell changes

Tags: excel, vba

not an expert here. Working with an huge excel table, some sort of sales pipeline. I'd like to achieve the following: if I change the value of a cell (that has data validation list), I want the value of another cell on the same row to change. Basically, if an opportunity changes into "Won", I want the probability cell of the same row to change into 100%.
I've searched a bit and i've found solutions but most of them are based on std excel use, while I'm specifically using a table (ListObject). Do I have to "behave" differently?

I haven't written any code for this, as my coding skills are basic and based on internet copy/paste + editing. Using a formula isn't an option as I want that cell still to be editable for those cases when the opportunity isn't "Won".

Edit:
What I've done so far is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.ListObjects("tblSalesPipeline").ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "Won" Then
        MsgBox "Congratulations!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Idiot!"
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Clearly, the MsbBox-es are just tests to see if it works. What I have now to understand is how to address to the specific row in the Probability column...

Comment: You can look for [`Worksheet_Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) in VBA code for this purpose.

Comment: I guessed so. What I need to understand it's if I need to treat it differently as I'm working with a Table. In other words, I don't know how to tell Excel to check if what changed in the table is something in the columns with the header "Status", and if so, if the change is a certain cell changed into "Won". and if so, identify the row of the "Won" cell, and put "100" in the cell with the header "Probability" in the same row only.

Comment: Use `Intersect` and `ListColumns("Status")`...

Comment: OK, studying it now. If you could give some more info, I'd appreciate a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the offset function (1st parameter is the row offset, 2nd parameter is the column offset + to move right, - to move left) assuming that the 'Probability' column is two columns to the right:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.ListObjects("tblSalesPipeline").ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "Won" Then
        Target.Offset(0,2).Value2 = 1
        MsgBox "Congratulations!"
```

Comment: Worth noting that *generally* you should also `Application.EnableEvents=False` at the beginning of this event handler (and then return it to `True` before the `End Sub`).